# Python benchmarking code is not performing well

Tags: python, multiprocessing, dask, benchmarking

I am trying to write a benchmarking tool from scratch in python. Unfortunately, no matter how I try, my code can not reach the performance of other benchmarking tools like `wrk/wrk2`. Using wr2 I can make 42k reqs/s while my code can create only up to 2200 reqs/s. I have tried multiple ways to parallelize the code execution(using multiprocessing, parallel computing libraries like [Dask](https://tutorial.dask.org/00_overview.html). But seems like I am hitting an upper bound of capacity. I understand `wrk/wrk2` is written in C which can be one reason but still 42k vs 2200 seems very low.

This is my code using multiprocessing:

```
import time
import multiprocessing
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
import requests

# import multiprocessing as mp

num_workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()  


output = multiprocessing.Queue()
def runner(number_of_request):
    output=""
    for i in range(number_of_request):
        try:
            output+=str(requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/").text)
        except:
            pass
        # print(output)
    
    return output


if __name__ == '__main__':
    number_of_request = 1000
    start = time.time()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_workers)
    outputs = [pool.apply_async(runner, args = (number_of_request,)) for x in range(num_workers)]
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    duration = time.time() - start 
    req_s = (number_of_request*num_workers)/duration
    print("duration =", time.time() - start)
    print(req_s)
```

I have tried with different number of workers and `number_of_request`, but it does not change that much.

Now, I am trying to understand if I am really hitting the upper limit or I am doing something wrong. The server is running in localhost and written in Java Spring.

Comment: Hi,  this question is more suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: `requests` is a high level framework using many unnecessary resources. For benchmarking you have to go to the lowest level possible, like sockets or even raw sockets.